# Joomla - Independent SQL query

Tags: php, joomla

I'm wondering if someone can give me a bit of a hand.

I'm trying to write a query inside a PHP file in Joomla and its not really working that well, nothing is being output.

I'm very new to this Joomla stuff, so if someone could let me know where I'm going wrong that would be great.

My code is as follows:

```
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();
$query = "SELECT fullname FROM jos_jxzine_authors WHERE published = '1'";
$db->setQuery($query);
$column = $db->loadResultArray();

echo JHTML::_('select.options', $column, 'value', 'text', $this->categoryMap);
```

Cheers,

Comment: Have you done 'print_r($column);' or 'var_dump($column);' to make sure the query is working? You could also put "if($db->getErrorNum()){echo $db->stderr();}' after '$column = $db->loadResultArray();', which will let you know if mysql is spitting out any errors. As for figuring out what's going on with the JHTML::_ method, have you turned on error reporting in your administrative back-end? (Go to Global Configuration, Server Tab, select 'Maximum' in the 'Error Reporting' dropdown).

Answer (score 1):

Please use this query

```
$query = "SELECT fullname FROM `#__jxzine_authors` WHERE published = '1'";
```

joomla will itself add db prefix. So you must use `#_` instead of `jos`