# Joomla JFactory doesn't work for a particular table

Tags: database, joomla

I would like extract data from a DB table (that has data - 3 record) using JFactory class in my PHP Code. I have created this code

```
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();                              
$query = "select * from fmw_formazioni";
$db->setQuery($query);
$db->query();    
print_r($db->loadResultArray());
```

but it doesn't work (number of record 0). If I change table (I insert another table name that have table records) this code works! What is the matter?

The code works if I call it in another place of my global code and if I execute query in my phpMyAdmin it works. It seems a problem of that table (fmw_formazioni). Can you help me?

Comment: can you try "SELECT * FROM #_formazioni" ? question related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811992/joomla-independant-sql-query

Comment: What version of Joomla are you using?

Comment: The problem was that my table was empty. Another query has deleted all rows in table.

Answer (score 0):

By default `loadResultArray()` takes 0 offset or the first column. So you probably have no data. Are you sure you want to use this function?

Also note that this function have been [removed](http://docs.joomla.org/Potential_backward_compatibility_issues_in_Joomla_3.0_and_Joomla_Platform_12.1#JDatabase) in favor of `loadColumn()` as of 3.x.

What version are you using?